# Condense gcc statement

Tags: macos, gcc, libusb

I'm using [OS X Mavericks (10.9)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks%27). Is there a way to condense my `gcc` command a bit, so I don't have to type the following verbose version of a command just to compile?

```
gcc -L /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9/lib -I /usr/local/include -o xout usbtest.c -l usb-1.0
```

Comment: Consider writing a Makefile.  See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: You know, it's not 1980 any more, you can use a graphical IDE, that kind of stuff exists even on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull)'s advice and write a Makefile, then all you'll have to do is type:

```
make
```

Here is a quick hint at the sort of thing you'll need:

```
INCLUDES=/usr/local/include
LDIRS=/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9/lib
LIBS=usb-1.0
CC=gcc

all: xout

xout: usbtest.c
    $(CC) -L $(LDIRS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o xout usbtest.c -l $(LIBS)
```